# How append a row line to an existing csv file using opencsv in java

Tags: java, opencsv

Im using `CSVWriter(OpenCSV)` to write the data into `CSV` in `Java`.

Can any one please help me to append data to the existing data?

I tried opening the file as given below

```
FileWriter pw = new FileWriter("F:\\data.csv",true);
```

But I could able to see the Old content is replaced and only the new data is available in the file? 
I want the old data along with new data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing at the end of a file via opencsv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741564/writing-at-the-end-of-a-file-via-opencsv)

Comment: This seems to have been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741564/writing-at-the-end-of-a-file-via-opencsv I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried in the same way. But I could see only the latest row and the already existing row is not availble in the CSV

Answer (score 4):

If you are using openCSV, then do something like this :-

`CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv, true));`

here is full example:-

```
import java.io.FileWriter;

import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter;

public class AppendToCSVExample
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
   {
      String csv = "data.csv";
      CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv, true));

      String [] record = "3,David,Feezor,USA,40".split(",");

      writer.writeNext(record);

      writer.close();
   }
}
```

To append new record on existing .csv file, you have to enable append mechanism of FileWritter class(here 'true' - second argument) which enables append feature of FileWritter class.

Hope this may work for you.

Comment: I tried in the same way. But I could see only the latest row and the already existing row is not availble in the CSV

Comment: if I would use `StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder` ?

Answer (score 0):

I was using :

CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(csvOutput)));
When I used:

CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csvOutput, true));

IT Worked !