# Writing test Result into CSV file

Tags: java, webdriver, opencsv

I need your support as I just start to learn Java and automation testing, script is working fine with me but only I have problem when extracting test result into CSV file only one row written and keep override on this row so i need your support how to save all test result and print it in csv file, i am using OpenCSV

```
if (drivertest.getCurrentUrl().equalsIgnoreCase(CreateErrorUrl)) {
    String TicketAlreadyCreated = drivertest.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/strong")).getText();
    System.out.println(TicketAlreadyCreated);
    csvWriter.writeNext(new String[] { Account, TicketAlreadyCreated });
    csvWriter.close();
} else {                
    String CreationDone = drivertest.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div")).getText();
    System.out.println(CreationDone);
    csvWriter.writeNext(new String[] { Account, CreationDone });
    csvWriter.close();
```

Comment: Can you be more specific, are you wanting to save all the results from different files into a single csv file? or did you mean to say in a single run the rows are getting overwritten?

Comment: Have you checked this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741564/writing-at-the-end-of-a-file-via-opencsv (using `FileWriter(file_name, true)`)?

Comment: Adithya Morampudi: yes i mean that in a single run the rows are getting overwritten

Comment: bene: i need to write all data in only one csv file but rows should be added in every run as it is include loop for more than one account